# Insert view/block/panel in static page

Tags: views, blocks, panels

I would like to create static pages (because I don't want to go through creating a proper theme) but still use Drupal as a CMS. For example, I might create a content type to add images to my Drupal site and then create a view to display images in a particular way. I would then like to be able to insert the code that will display that view in my static page. How would I go about doing this for views, blocks and panels? I am using Drupal 7.

Your help is much appreciated.

Kamal

Comment: what you means about static page?  `html` ??? or a `.php` that there is not any dynamic part ( php that every thing in it is html tags ? )

Comment: I think you are looking for https://drupal.org/project/web_widgets or https://drupal.org/project/embed_views

Comment: zhilevan, the pages would be php in which I would insert a code like <?php insert_view('view_name'); ?> I am guessing I will need some sort of includes to let it know the drupal functions it has access to.

Thanks, Bala. I'll check them out.

Comment: Bala, if you make your comment into an answer, I will mark it as such. I ended using panels within my template to completely change the content area with CSS injector for custom CSS, which seems to work well for me. Thanks.